# Div refuse to be 100% height of parent

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little problem with the left "bar" in my html (see snippet below).

It will not be 100% height of parent. I've been trying for a few hour but not sure why it will not be 100% height.

The result I want to get is found [here](https://codepen.io/aleksblago/pen/ONapLa)

Please note that I've can't use the following code, since this use for a webpart in SharePoint.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.pvClientViewer_704ae523 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523 {
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em 4em 2em 2em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523>h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 {
  counter-reset: my_awesome_list;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -3.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 {
  counter-increment: my_awesome_list;
  margin: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:before {
  content: counter(my_awesome_list, decimal-leading-zero);
  background: #fff;
  border: 10px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 2.6em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 2.6em;
  z-index: 2
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:nth-child(n+1):before {
  background: #8e44ad;
  border-color: #2c3e50;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #8e44ad
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:nth-child(n+1)>span {
  background: #8e44ad
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 span {
  background: #8e44ad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2em;
  padding: 1.2em 2em 1.2em 3em;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 span:after {
  background: 0 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  right: 2%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transform: rotate(3deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="pvClientViewer_704ae523">
  <section class="list_intro_704ae523">
  </section>
  <section class="awesome_list_704ae523">
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Illum placeat aut nam distinctio officiis dolore deset.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Dignissimos aliquam, velit odio magni mollitia quos recusate.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Labore quibusdam voluptatibus nobis minima reprehen.</span></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Do anyone have an idea how to fix this, since I'm really blank right now.

Comment: I look at the demo and don't really understand the problem... Can you highlight the problematic div somehow? Or provide a screenshot of how you want things to look?

Comment: @Oram Run the snippet and you can see that the bar on the left (between 2 and 3) is only around 100px in height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the element positioned:

```css
.pvClientViewer_704ae523 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  position:relative;
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523 {
  position:absolute;
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em 4em 2em 2em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523>h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 {
  counter-reset: my_awesome_list;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 {
  counter-increment: my_awesome_list;
  margin: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:before {
  content: counter(my_awesome_list, decimal-leading-zero);
  background: #fff;
  border: 10px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 2.6em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 2.6em;
  z-index: 2
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:nth-child(n+1):before {
  background: #8e44ad;
  border-color: #2c3e50;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #8e44ad
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:nth-child(n+1)>span {
  background: #8e44ad
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 span {
  background: #8e44ad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2em;
  padding: 1.2em 2em 1.2em 3em;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 span:after {
  background: 0 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  right: 2%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transform: rotate(3deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="pvClientViewer_704ae523">
  <section class="list_intro_704ae523">
  </section>
  <section class="awesome_list_704ae523">
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Illum placeat aut nam distinctio officiis dolore deset.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Dignissimos aliquam, velit odio magni mollitia quos recusate.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Labore quibusdam voluptatibus nobis minima reprehen.</span></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting explicit height anywhere.... but i notice that you give your `html` and `body` height 100%. Are you trying to achieve 100% the window height? if so add this tag in the head of your document 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, then you can make a div 100% window height like this `height: 100vh` or 100% width like this `width: 100vw`

Answer (score 0):

Change the border-box to a content-box, and adjust the padding to suit.

```
.list-intro {
  background: #2C3E50;
  color: #FFF;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em 0em 2em 0em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your issue:

> I have used `position: absolute;` to your box to solve your bug.

```css
.pvClientViewer_704ae523 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  /*margin-left:20px;*/
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523 {
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em 4em 2em 2em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523>h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 {
  counter-reset: my_awesome_list;
  display: inline-block;
  /*margin-left: -3.4em;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 {
  counter-increment: my_awesome_list;
  margin: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:before {
  content: counter(my_awesome_list, decimal-leading-zero);
  background: #fff;
  border: 10px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 2.6em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 2.6em;
  z-index: 2
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:nth-child(n+1):before {
  background: #8e44ad;
  border-color: #2c3e50;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #8e44ad
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:nth-child(n+1)>span {
  background: #8e44ad
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 span {
  background: #8e44ad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2em;
  padding: 1.2em 2em 1.2em 3em;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 span:after {
  background: 0 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  right: 2%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transform: rotate(3deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="pvClientViewer_704ae523">
  <section class="list_intro_704ae523">
  </section>
  <section class="awesome_list_704ae523">
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Illum placeat aut nam distinctio officiis dolore deset.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Dignissimos aliquam, velit odio magni mollitia quos recusate.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Labore quibusdam voluptatibus nobis minima reprehen.</span></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

In class `.pvClientViewer_704ae523`  I added the property - `display: flex;`

and in class `.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523` I removed these properties - `padding: 2em 4em 2em 2em; height: 100%;`

See if this is what you want.

```css
.pvClientViewer_704ae523 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523 {
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .list_intro_704ae523>h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 {
  counter-reset: my_awesome_list;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -3.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 {
  counter-increment: my_awesome_list;
  margin: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:before {
  content: counter(my_awesome_list, decimal-leading-zero);
  background: #fff;
  border: 10px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 2.6em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 2.6em;
  z-index: 2
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:nth-child(n+1):before {
  background: #8e44ad;
  border-color: #2c3e50;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #8e44ad
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523:nth-child(n+1)>span {
  background: #8e44ad
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 span {
  background: #8e44ad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2em;
  padding: 1.2em 2em 1.2em 3em;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.pvClientViewer_704ae523 .awesome_list_704ae523 .awesome_list_item_704ae523 span:after {
  background: 0 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  right: 2%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transform: rotate(3deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="pvClientViewer_704ae523">
  <section class="list_intro_704ae523">
  </section>
  <section class="awesome_list_704ae523">
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Illum placeat aut nam distinctio officiis dolore deset.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Dignissimos aliquam, velit odio magni mollitia quos recusate.</span></div>
    <div class="awesome_list_item_704ae523"><span>Labore quibusdam voluptatibus nobis minima reprehen.</span></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the way of displaying.
You need to display: block; and float: left;

```
.list-intro {
background: #2C3E50;
color: #FFF;
box-sizing: none;
display: block;
padding: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
float: left;
```

}